How can I pass a parameter to Async function in Python
So I am using Python Flask (ik, not optimal, but it is what I know.) However, I am getting an error that I understand, but I am not familiar enough with async to be able to solve it myself. I lack some syntax knowledge too.
This is the bit of code I got from this link (https://deepgram.com/learn/live-transcription-flask) :
async def process_audio(fast_socket: web.WebSocketResponse, language):
    async def get_transcript(data: Dict) -> None:
        if 'channel' in data:
            transcript = data['channel']['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
        
            if transcript:
                await fast_socket.send_str(transcript)

    deepgram_socket = await connect_to_deepgram(get_transcript, language)

    return deepgram_socket
async def connect_to_deepgram(transcript_received_handler: Callable[[Dict], None], language) -> str:
    try:
        socket = await dg_client.transcription.live({'punctuate': False, 'interim_results': False, 'language': language, 'model': 'nova-2', 'timeout' : 300})        
        socket.registerHandler(socket.event.CLOSE, lambda c: print(f'Connection closed with code {c}.'))
        socket.registerHandler(socket.event.TRANSCRIPT_RECEIVED, transcript_received_handler)

        return socket
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f'Could not open socket: {e}')   
async def socket(request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    await ws.prepare(request) 

    deepgram_socket = await process_audio(ws, language)

    while True:
        data = await ws.receive_bytes()

        

        deepgram_socket.send(data)

As you can see, I am trying to add a language parameter. I am using python Flask, so I tried adding calling the session variable I created everytime the user logs in which has the language saved, but it doesn't work. So now, I am trying to parse the language parameter from the JavaScript into the Python. Here is the JavaScript:
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5555/listen?language=${language}');


        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
            if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm'))
                return alert('Browser not supported');

            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                mimeType: 'audio/webm',
            });




            mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', async (event) => {
                if (event.data.size > 0 && socket.readyState == 1) {
                    socket.send(event.data);
                }
            });





            mediaRecorder.start(100);
        });
    });

How can I add a parameter to change the language that Deepgram recognizes? Would there be a better way to dynamically change the language parameter? Maybe throught the URL? There is probably some important code I didn't put, but when the language parameter is set to a static value like 'de' for German (deutsch), everything works.

Your code doesn't appear to define the variable at all. In aiohttp, you'd get the URL parameter with request.query.get("language", "en") or similar. I suspect Flask is almost identical.

@SamBull, I have it saved elsewhere, I just didnt show it. Ive added it now to the question.
